# Why i cannot call the default constructor while having a private constructor?

Tags: c#

i have the following class with a private overloaded constructor

```
 class Car
    {
        string _Make;
        string _Model;

        Car(string make, string model)
        {
            _Make = make;
            _Model = model;
        }
    }
```

then i've tried to call the default constructor of the above class

```
class Daytona
{
    public int Foo()
    {
        Car c = new Car(); //COMPILATION ERROR

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Note both classes are in the same namespace!

i could not create an instance of the Car using its default constructor. But **either i create a default constructor or not i should be able to access the default constructor**. but i why this error occurred?

<strike>okay fellows, something bad happened with VS 2010, when i restarted my machine VS 2010 compiled the above code. so that problem was solved.</strike>

its my compiler, when i recompiled it, again brought the error, in line `" Car c = new Car();"` error was *MyNamespace.Car.Car(string, string) is inaccessible due to its protection level*

But i want to drag this top to a new area, why would someone want to create a private constructor? (the above code just for testing!)

Comment: You rarely want `private` constructors (singleton is just about it) consider carefully what you are using for it!

Comment: A private constructor is also fairly common when you want to force all callers to use a common cache or object pool. A static factory method instead of a constructor allows the class author to control when instances are created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Car
    {
        string _Make;
        string _Model;

        public Car(){}    

        public Car(string make, string model)
        {
            _Make = make;
            _Model = model;
        }
    }
```

Make it public instead, but you also need to add a parameterless constructor if you want to call it without parameters. The default constructor is no longer implicitly defined if you define another constructor (with parameters)

Answer (score 5):

You do not have a *public* constructor of `class Car` that does not require arguments to be passed. Therefore you need to add this constructor. This constructor has to be explicitly defined when you've already defined another constructor. I also added `public` to the constructor you already had.

```
public class Car
{
    string _Make;
    string _Model;

    public Car()
    {
        // Default constructor - does not require arguments
    }

    public Car(string make, string model)
    {
        _Make = make;
        _Model = model;
    }
}
```

The second constructor can still be private if you prefer, but you won't be able to call it directly.

Now you can do either:

```
Car A = new Car(); // Creates a new instance, does not set anything
Car B = new Car("MyMake", "MyModel"); // Creates a new instance, sets make and model
```

Answer (score 2):

Why a private or protected (for subclassed classes) constructor?  Factories are perfect examples, if you want to provide easy to use creation factories for a class that may have complex settings etc then having a private constructor would prevent someone from creating an instance without providing adequate values:

Example:

```
public class Car
{

   public static Car CreateNew()
   {
      Car c = new Car();
      c.Engine = Engine.CreateNew(4);  // 4 cyl
      //set properties so that the object will behave correctly...
      return c;
   }
   public static Car CreateNew(string make, string model, Engine e)
   {
     Car c = new Car(make,model);
     c.Engine = e;
   }
   private Car(){
   }

   private Car( string make, string model) : this() {
      Make = make;
      Model = model;
   }
   public string Make { get; set; }
   public string Model {get; set; }

   public Engine {get; private set; }

   //other properties that maybe are not so simple or understood
   //or properties that need to be set to control other behaviors..

}
```

Now I've created factories to create `Car`, these factory methods are the only way to create instances of the class.